# PLaying Video with VLCJ

Tags: java, video, javafx, jmf, vlcj

I try to play a video in a java application using VLCJ.
I followed this tuto : [VLCJ tuto](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html) , but I got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Pointer.initIDs()I

I have tested JMF and JavaFX. JMF can't play AVI video, and JavaFX is difficult for me .
Can you give me an other simple API who can do what I need ?

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Make sure that the JVM bit level is the same as the DLLs you are trying to load (ie if you have the 32 bit VLC player installed, then you need to use a 32 bit JVM)

Comment: I have both 32Bit. now i have an other Error when i tried an older VLCJ version : 
Warning: jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/win32-amd64/jnidispatch.dll) not found in resource path
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnidispatch in java.library.path

Comment: Consider [this](https://github.com/twall/jna/issues/281) discussion - You also need to make sure that the DLL's are in the right location as described by the requirements of JVLC

Comment: I have already be in this discussion, but I still got the probleme

Comment: It looks to me like the jnidispatch library has been found, but the library that was found is not the same version as the JNA jar file you are using expects.  MadProgrammer's link looks on point to me, did you try "-Djna.nosys=true" when you start your JVM?

Comment: I solved the problem by setting the  jna.nosys to true, and jna.boot.path to my folder who contains jna and dll.  But now I have to System.setproperties() in my code. How can I tell java that I have changed this properties without code?